# How do I install ubuntu server to dell edge gateway 3001

Tags: server, dell

Did anyone try to install ubuntu server to a dell edge gateway 3001(no video port)? I have successfully installed an unattended ubuntu server to other devices but not for dell edge gateway 3001. the device is not booting the installer, I have tried to use different flash drive tools and filesystem but still no luck.

Comment: http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-edge-gateway-3000-series_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf > Starts on page 52.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks, I already read it, but the guide was for ubuntu core 16. I'm trying the same steps using ubuntu server and it isn't working.

Comment: The only supported version ***is*** Ubuntu Core (or Windows for IoT), not regular desktop/server versions. Please contact Dell support for further informations.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? How?

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch the uefi boot sequence to boot from a different drive. use the cli to change uefi boot settings. I installed ubuntu server on a flash drive on a different computer with no network access and openssh installed then moved the drive over to the edge gateway 3001. boot up the gateway with a keyboard and network connected wait for it to finish booting. Hit enter once then blindly loggin with your username and pw, then run command "sudo dhclient -v" enter sudo pw hit enter. after you should be able to see the device on the network then login through ssh.